# Calculate mean of raster excluding values in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, zonal-statistics

I want to calculate the mean value of a specific region a raster data layer (being a GeoTIFF file), using the [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000) tool in ArcMap.

However, some of the values are faulty and need to be excluded in the calculation.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can logically identify the values you want to exclude you can simply set them to 'NoData' using the [Set Null](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/set-null.htm) toolset. If you're already using the Spatial Analyst extension to access Zonal Statistics you will have access to Set Null.